# AngularJS - Custom filter with specific JSON object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

Example
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rzgWr/840/)

In my example i pretend that professionalarea.description in my json is my categories filter and not the pants. The problem is when I try to insert professionalarea.description doesn't work.
I don't understand why Because if I insert the other threads of my json it works fine but when I try to make the way to the professionalarea.description doesn't work.

JSON:

```
{
            "Categoria": "Informática",
            "Title": "Consultor DBA Oracle",
            "Empresa": "Infosistemas",
            "Data": "2016-07-11",
            "id": "1",
            "Localidade": "Lisboa", 
            "professionalarea": {
                "idAreaProfissional":1,
                "description":"IT"
            },
            "Horario": "Estágio Profissional"
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work fine.  Is there something I am missing here??

http://jsfiddle.net/rzgWr/841/

Using this seems to work fine

```
{{player.professionalarea.description}}
```

Comment: where you put the json is works but i want in my filter. Where is pant size filter i want the professionalarea.description filter. In my line 59 jsfiddle i have a comment